# Woocommerce redirect thankyou page based on product ID doesn't empty Cart

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, redirect

In WooCommerce, I am using the following code to redirect users to custom thank you page after purchase of specific product. It gets the Product ID then redirects based on that ID.

I've pasted the code below in my **functions.php**:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_thankyou_1month' );

function redirect_thankyou_1month(){

    /* do nothing if we are not on the appropriate page */
    if( !is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) || empty( $_GET['key'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $_GET['key'] );
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if( $item['product_id'] == 2781 ) {
            wp_redirect( '/ar1m/' );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is after purchase when using this snippet the items purchased remain in cart. I've used this particular code so Tracking can still occur; however, I can use an alternate method of tracking if need be, so I'm not against using the `woocommerce_get_return_url`...

Answer (score 1):

Your actual code is a bit outdated and not so secure… Since WooCommerce 3 Order items are now Objects and `$item['product_id']` is replaced by `$item->get_product_id()`.

You should try first to use `woocommerce_get_return_url` like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_get_return_url', 'custom_order_received_return_url', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_received_redirect( $return_url, $order ){
    // HERE define your products IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array(741);

    // HERE define your redirection URL (with the order ID as argument if needed)
    $redirection_url = home_url('/ar1m/');

    if ( is_ssl() || get_option( 'woocommerce_force_ssl_checkout' ) == 'yes' ) {
        $redirection_url = str_replace( 'http:', 'https:', $redirection_url );
    }

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if( in_array( $item->get_product_id(), $product_ids ) ) {
            return $redirection_url;
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

---

If not, the following code will make a custom redirection on "Order received" page for defined product ID(s), **emptying cart** (if needed) and checking that the order is valid:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_order_received_redirect' );
function custom_order_received_redirect(){
    // Only on order received (thankyou) page for a valid Order ID
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')
        && ( $order_id = absint( get_query_var('order-received') ) )
        && get_post_type($order_id) === 'shop_order'
        && isset( $_GET['key'] ) ) {

        // Empty cart
        if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        }

        // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        // Check that the order key is valid
        if( is_a($order, 'WC_Order') && $order->get_order_key() === esc_attr($_GET['key']) ) {

            // HERE define your products IDs in the array
            $product_ids = array(2781);

            // HERE define your redirection URL (with the order ID as argument if needed)
            $redirection_url = home_url("/ar1m/");

            // Loop through order items
            foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                if( in_array( $item->get_product_id(), $product_ids ) ) {
                    wp_redirect( $redirection_url );
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

You can pass the **Order ID** in the redirection url like:

```
$redirection_url = home_url("/ar1m/?order_id=$order_id");
```

Then you will be able to get the **Order ID** on your redirected page using:

```
if( isset($_GET['order_id']) && get_post_type($_GET['order_id']) === 'shop_order' ) {
    $order_id = absint($_GET['order_id']);
}
```